# nginx: Redirects URL's to extensionless pages not working on home page

Tags: nginx, php, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to automatically redirect pages with a PHP extension to a non extension page version e.g `example.com/page.php` to `example.com/page`. I've managed to get this working for all pages except my home page and a dynamic page. These pages both return a `404` error page.

For the home page if I try to visit `example.com` I get a `404` response, but if I visit `example.com/index` then the home page loads.

I obviously want the home page to load like `example.com` and the dynamic page should load like `example.com/check/something.com`.

Here's the relevant code:

```
server {

   index  index.php index.html index.htm;

   location / {
        try_files  $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
        sendfile   off;

        # returns a 404 e.g example.com/check/something.com
        rewrite ^/check/(.*)$ /check.php?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check;
   }

    # If PHP extension then 301 redirect to semantic URL
    location ~ ^(.*)\.php$ {
        return 301  $scheme://$server_name$1$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*) {
       try_files $uri.php @static; # If static, serve it in @static

       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

       include fastcgi_params;
    } 

    location @static {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

  }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your `location / { ... }` block is never visited - because `location ~ ^/(.*)` will match any URI not ending with `.php`.

Comment: @Richard Smith, Thanks, what would be the best way to fix this? I need the `location /` block so can't really change it. I can't figure out how to redirect to non PHP pages without using `location ~ ^/(.*)` regex.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a `location` block that's never used. Your `location ~ ^/(.*)` block should be the `location /` block. The `rewrite` should be inside a `location /check/` block. And the homepage should be inside a `location = /` block.

Comment: @Richard Smith, I've commented out the `location /` block and added the check and homepage block, but I'm still getting a `404` for both of them. `location = / {  try_files /index.php?$args;
  }
    location /check/ {
        rewrite ^/check/(.*)$ /check.php?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check;
    }`

Comment: Nginx will not restart with the edits in your comment as `try_files` has an incorrect number of parameters. You are internally rewriting to a URI ending with `.php`. You should be rewriting to `/index` and `/check`.

Comment: @Richard Smith, sorry, I don't know what you mean by 'You should be rewriting to /index and /check.' Like this? `location = /index {` and `location /check {`

Comment: No. I mean like: `rewrite ^/check/(.*)$ /check?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check last;` as `/check` is the URI for the script called `check.php`.

Comment: @Richard Smith, I'm still getting a `404` response for the `location /check/` block. The index block is loading correctly now.`location = / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index last;
    }`
and
   `location /check/ {
        rewrite ^/check/(.*)$ /check?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check last;
    }`